# Redirect user to the secure connection when hit the domain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have written a rule in .htaccess it was working great according to the requirement now there is a slight change in the requirement and I am confuse that how can I accomplish that by changing my previous rule the first rule which is working is that when when ever user hit the domain example.com or www.example.com user should be redirected to

> https://www.example.com/blog/

This rule is working now the next requirement is that when user hit the domain

> http://www.hkdcrandom.com/blog/lorem-ipsum/

OR

> http://www.hkdcrandom.com/blog/lorem-ipsum/

He should redirect to

> https://www.hkdcrandom.com/blog/lorem-ipsum/

But this thing is not working here is the rule I have written so far.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Can any one tell me what am I doing wrong

Comment: So basicaly you want the url to always be https?

Comment: Yes but I need some more conditions to run along with this

Comment: Like when user hit `example.com` or `www.example.com` he should redirected to `https://www.example.com/blog/` this condition is working the condition that is not working is that when user hit the domain like `http://www.hkdcrandom.com/blog/lorem-ipsum/` he is not redirecting to secure connection

Comment: try this --> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

Comment: No sir this is not working

Answer (score 0):

We currently use

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # Force https and www
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

    # Force www
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

    # The rest of your rules
    RewriteBase /blog/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
 </IfModule>
```

Comment: This don't work in this case `http://www.example.com/blog/lorem-ipsum/`

Comment: And also it is redirecting 4 times

Comment: I edited slightly the top conditions and rules.. I think it is because of the RewriteBase rule `http://www.example.com/blog/lorem-ipsum/` is not working. And you are checking if a file or directory is not targetted by the url, but the `^index\.php$ - [L]` puts in a file before checking conditions?

Comment: Then I don’t think I can help you out :(

Comment: It's ok nothing to get sad will fix this one way or other actually there is a sure short way to do so but that is not recommended or you could say it is a very bad practice